# Return User Friendly or Clean SOAP Exception from ASMX Web Services C#

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, asmx, soapfault

i have hardtime to change returned SOAP Message from Exception in ASMX Web Services C#.
Here is returned Soap Message Exception right now :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.ApplicationException: Module Authorization Failed
   at BackEnd.Services.Models.ModuleCredential.IsValid(String serviceName)
   at BackEnd.DashboardPSI.HelloWorld()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and i want to change to like this :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Server was unable to process request. ---> Module Authorization Failed</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm using ASMX WebServices at NetFramework 4.5. and using SoapExtension to Log the exception.
Thanks

```
public class Base: System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Module Authorization Failed");
        }
    }
```

**Updated**
So this fault return with inner exception happens when in development env, when i put in production env, the inner exception is hide. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand - is your code the *server* or the *client* in this case? Meaning, is it your service that's throwing this exception? If so, can you post that code? Why can't you change the exception being thrown? If you're the consumer (client) of the web service, *you can't change what's being returned*, but you can catch it and handle however you like. Also, SOAP isn't really designed for *user-friendliness*... it's a machine-to-machine protocol

Comment: my code is on the server, and my service throw this exception only using `throw new Exception("Module Authorization Failed")` @CoolBots

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773546/hiding-the-stacktrace-for-an-exception-returned-by-a-asp-net-webmethod

Comment: still not found how to change faultstring result

Answer (score 0):

So this fault return with inner exception happens when in development env, when i put in production env, the inner exception is hide.
Thanks

Comment: Is this just an addition to your original question? If so, please edit the question.